# Cannot login to heroku using cmd.exe

Tags: heroku

I am following the advice from various forums, but no luck up to now.

I open cmd.exe

I go to Programme\Heroku\App (folder set up by me)

I type heroku login

I get the error "No such file or directory"

?

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: And you already did try the dir command to see if heroku is an exe of cmd file in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Heroku folder to your $PATH - when you move into your app, cmd.exe cannot find anything called `heroku` in the App/ folder.

How did you install Heroku? Perhaps try the Toolbelt method, which should handle it for you? https://toolbelt.heroku.com/